# SQL Server - Decimal values not precisely calculated

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, decimal, precision, sqldatatypes

For the below calculation, the expected result is `-0.0000671`. But the result of the code is `-0.00006800000`.

```
declare 
    @V_A        decimal (38,11) = 99.99329,
    @V_B        decimal (38,11) = 100,
    @V_RESULT   decimal (38,11);

    print '@V_A = '+cast(@V_A as varchar) --Printed as "99.99329000000"
    print '@V_B = '+cast(@V_B as varchar) --Printed as "100.00000000000"
    SET @V_RESULT = (@V_A / @V_B) - 1;
    print '@V_RESULT = '+cast(@V_RESULT as varchar) --Printed as "-0.00006800000"
```

Interestingly, the below code returns exact result as expected.

```
select (99.99329 / 100) - 1  --Returns "-0.000067100".
```

Could you please help me to get the same output in the above T-SQL code? I don't want to use `float` as it will increase decimal places. Thanks in advance.

**Environment: Azure SQL DB, DTU based.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: select (99.99329000000 / 100)  is not 100.00  it is like select (99.99329000000 / cast(100.00 as int) )  so it looks like an int - the precision seems to increase when the int is auto cast back to what is needed to do the math.

Comment: @Progman Unfortunately No.

Comment: @SqlSurfer I casted both values. But still the same issue.
```select (cast(99.99329 as decimal(38,11))/ cast(100 as decimal(38,11))) - 1```

Answer (score 0):

Casting to float during calculation resolves the issue.

```
    @V_A        decimal (38,11) = 99.99329,
    @V_B        decimal (38,11) = 100,
    @V_RESULT   decimal (38,11);

    print '@V_A = '+cast(@V_A as varchar)  --Printed as "99.99329000000"
    print '@V_B = '+cast(@V_B as varchar)  --Printed as 100.00000000000
    SET @V_RESULT = (cast(@V_A as float) / cast(@V_B as float)) - 1;  --Printed as -0.00006710000
    print '@V_RESULT = '+cast(@V_RESULT as varchar)
```

Comment: I meant not to use (declare) the variables as ```float```. Sorry, if it misled.